# How to make div height equal to width in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid to layout a thumbnail gallery, no Javascript or any other responsive techniques. I would like to set the height of thumbnails to be as its width (1:1) square ratio.
Why? when the page loads I need the thumbnail div's to take space, because now if there is no Image inside the thumbnails div it doesn't take any space.

Here is a Live example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMCULIDQUOBX

Here is the Code:

```
.container {max-width: 900px;}
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
.thumbnail {box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);}
img {width: 100%; display: block;}
```

...............................

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">

    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="large-image.jpg">
        <img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      ...... same as above ......
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      ...... same as above ......
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      ...... same as above ......
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The Code above divides the width (900px) into four fractions, and the 4 thumbnails are placed in 1 row. That's why I don't define any width.
If Images don't load, the thumbnail div wont even be visible.
In other words, if you disable images in browser, thumbnail div should take space in a square shape.
How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: There is no CSS-Grid method of creating squares based on `fr` units`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Comment: _“when the page loads I need the thumbnail div's to take space”_ - then provide the actual image dimensions via `width` and `height` attributes in the HTML, so that the browser will know what the aspect ratio is upfront ... then it can calculate the _correct_ height according to the width the image is _display with_ before it has loaded the actual image.

Comment: use max-* properties

Comment: @CBroe I couldn't do that, the layout will break when resizing browser window.

Comment: Why would it do that then?

Comment: @CBroe here is a live example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMCULIDQUOBX

Comment: Nothing breaks, as soon as you add `height:auto` for the images in your CSS.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, in previous comment i meant "without defining width". Adding `height:auto` doesn't make the div a square. Try adding that and disable Images in browser.

Comment: First of all, who does that? Those users are likely used to pages looking different, so that would not bother me too much. (And if it was just the images failing to load for some other reason, it would still work.) Secondly, with images disabled, a bunch of red squares is not going to help the user much in any case - so adding proper alt attributes is the least thing you should do here. But if the squares are that important, you can switch to the padding-bottom hack, too, if you like, that’s an alternative method to achieve image “placeholders” of the correct aspect ratio/dimensions.

Comment: @CBroe on live website its not Red and it does include `alt` attribute. I have tried with padding-bottom with no luck. Will try again with some modification to make it work.

Comment: worked with padding-bottom hack as @CBroe suggested. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMD1UJKTU72Z

Answer (score 15):

The solution is to add an invisible square element (zero width and 100% bottom padding) to the grid, set equal height to all rows by `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`; and then reposition the invisible grid element as well as the first grid element to overlap.

So, your css file should look as the following:

```
.container {max-width: 900px;}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.gallery::before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.gallery > *:first-child{
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.thumbnail {box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);}

img {width: 100%; display: block;}
```

Comment: I have no clue what you've done but it works.

Comment: This is pure genius.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure how to do it with css grid but I know how to make `.thumbnail` maintain it's ratio.

I learnt this trick a while ago and I use it all the time since then.

```
.thumbnail{
   position: relative;
}
. thumbnail:before{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100% \* Percentage value in padding derived from the width  *\
}
.thumbnail > img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

the simplest solution is to add `aspect-ratio: 1` to the **css** of the child divs (the cells)

your parent div css `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` creates 4 columns

Adding `aspect-ratio: 1` to the **css** of the children of these columns forces each child to have the same **height** as **width**

```
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.thumbnail {
  aspect-ratio: 1
}


<div class="gallery">

     <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image1.jpeg">
     </div>

     <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image2.jpeg">
     </div>

     <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image3.jpeg">
     </div>

     <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image4.jpeg">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wonderful, not sure why it's not upvoted more!

Comment: This is a good solution, unfortunately iOS 14 and lower [doesn't support aspect-ratio](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio), so I had to go with a different solution.

Answer (score -3):

The big advantage is that CSS grid by default applies a similar height to its children.

Option is to restructure the HTML and reduce markup (HTML). You can add height to the `.gallery` class to make it look more square.

```css
.container {max-width: 900px; margin:0 auto;}
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
.thumbnail {display:block; box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);}
img {display:block; width:100%; height: auto;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gallery">
          <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail" href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
          </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail" href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/54278/pexels-photo-54278.jpeg">
          </a>
    
          <a class="thumbnail"  href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/242276/pexels-photo-242276.jpeg">
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does not address the principal point of the question - *" I would like to set the height of thumbnails to be as its width (1:1) square ratio."*

Comment: Here is a live example that you can experiment on: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMCULIDQUOBX